# MySqlClient cannot use ':=' (Set Operator)

Tags: mysql, .net

MySql version is 5.0.45.
First,I need to user PARTITION,RANK(),ROW_NUMBER() operator in query.
But this version isn't support.
So I must to use this ways instead:

```
SELECT t.*, 
   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM YOUR_TABLE t, 
   (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

But MySql.Data.MySqlClient seems not support the operator(:=)

```
Using MySql.Data.MySqlClient
        Dim con As MySqlConnection
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
        Dim myAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
        con = New MySqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "...."
        con.Open()
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, con)
        myAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rownum", 0)
        myAdapter.Fill(datatable)

        con.Close()
    End Using
```

It has some error like this

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= 0'

How to set variable in SELECT?

Comment: MySQL 5.0? Wow... back to 2005. I don't know if it's still supported, but I would strongly advice you upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Solution in the linked question. But I strongly suggest you upgrade to the current version of MySQL that supports window functions, if you need that feature.

Comment: Client don't want to upgrade their database server.